# Replacing a Saddle Valve with a Tee?

Tags: plumbing

I want to replace a saddle valve with a sharkbite (Close quarters + HVAC nearby, I really don't want to solder it :) ) slip tee (3/4" x 3/4" x 3/4"), but I can't seem to figure out the right couplers I would need to get the 1/4" copper ice maker line onto the 3/4" tee.

So far I'm thinking about getting the 3/4" slip tee + I already have a 3/4" copper pipe for the ice maker side of the slip tee, but after that I don't know what to put on the end of the 3/4" pipe.

How should I make the transition from the 3/4" pipe coming from the tee to the 1/4" ice maker line?

Here is the current situation

[image: Saddle Valve]

Comment: You would still want a cut-off valve for the run to the ice maker.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your solution/Ans already made up.  It is a Sharkbite tee with a valve cut off and a 1/4" fitting on the tee.

[image]

Link to item at Lowes:  [Sharkbite Tee with 1/4" fitting and valve](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00l7_-ewfhiTUkifPOFIGpgZ3v9HQ%3A1586320533599&source=hp&ei=lVSNXpD_IYiWtQXplIyACA&q=sharkbite%20tee%203%2F4&oq=sharkbite%20tee%203%2F4&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyAggAMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoHCCMQ6gIQJzoFCAAQgwE6BAgjECc6BQgAEJECOgQIABADOgQIABAKOggIABAWEAoQHjoFCAAQzQJKMQgXEi0wZzEyNWcxNTlnMTE1ZzExNWcxMTFnMTI5ZzExOGcxMTFnMTE1ZzExNWcxMjlKGwgYEhcwZzJnMmcxZzFnMWcxZzFnMWcyZzZnM1DpIFimzgFg8dABaAdwAHgAgAGrAYgBlxKSAQQwLjIxmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdperABCg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjQnZy_gNjoAhUIS60KHWkKA4AQ4dUDCAg&uact=5)

Comment: But if it's not a slip connector, how will I get it into the (rigid) copper pipe that I cut? I saw that on the Home Depot website, but I'm not sure I can use it :)

Comment: I cannot see the total pipe run, but if I look to the left of the picture, the pipe makes a 90 degree turn to the back.  You should be able to loosen the straps on that back section to allow the pipe to pull away  1 or two inches at the saddle cut to insert the tee.  Anyway, look at the pipe on both side to see if there is enough wiggle room that will allow you to use the fitting.  Another idea, don't know if it meets code, is to make another cut to use a straight slip fitting after the tee is inserted.

Comment: This would be the same as soldering a union at another spot, but since you don't want to solder, the slip coupler would be acting as the union.

Comment: Ah, so you're recommending that I use a slip coupler **along** with this?

Comment: Yes and the total time would be less than 30 minutes.

Comment: Use the slip coupler only after trying to get enough gap by removing the straps on the left and right segment and see if you can get enough gap to insert the Tee.  If not, then use the slip connector. To save time, just have the slip coupler available, if you can insert the Tee, then just return the slip coupler.